# SQL Server - Cost of adding a column to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an existing table containing just under 500 millions rows.  I would like to add a column (and a corresponding trigger) to keep track of the last modified time for the row.

I would like to ideally avoid or minimize any downtime.  Is it safe to assume creating that new column by making it nullable would *not* be a costly operation?  My other options would be to make that column non-nullable with a default value (which I think would be a very expensive operation) or creating a completely different table to deal with the last modified date.  This last option would ensure no downtime but I would much prefer the first option if it doesn't lock or cause adverse effects on the performance or availability of the database.

Comment: The nullable attribute isn't the important part. Adding a _default_ value would indeed make it **very** costly because all existing rows need to be updated. Adding the column without a default value (which does imply nullable) should be nearly instantaneous because it is only a metadata update if I'm not mistaken (at least it is in Postgres and Oracle)

Comment: I always used `ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD LastModified  AS GETDATE()`  which was pretty fast - i think i don't have to tell you that this is not a statement to be executed during business hours. Maybe you have a copy of your database where you can test the behaviour...

Comment: a trigger would be another solution where you have no downtime. but i am not a great fan of triggers for this purpose

Comment: Just had to do the same with about 1.5 mio rows... nullable was very fast, BIT with DEFAULT(0) took more than 30 minutes, Out of this I'd assume, that SQL Server does not add a new column physically into the space of the existing data (does anybody know what about this issue with a clustered index?). I'd probably solve this with a side table and a trigger... Depending on the parallel usage of your db...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Can you add a NOT NULL column without default value? (If the table has data.)

Comment: @jarlh: no you can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it has been said in the comments, it should be fine as long as you don't try to update the newly added columns for all columns.

It will only update metadata (see below) if:

- the new columns is nullable
- there is a default contraints with NOT NULL

However, if you need to update all the columns with different custom values, it is probably better to:

- create a new table `tableTemp`
- copy data from `YourTable` to `tableTemp`
- remove foreign keys on `YourTable`
- rename `YourTable` to `YourTableOld`
- rename `tableTemp` to `YourTable`
- create foreign key
- make sure no data have been added after the copy, otherwise add what is missing to the new table

The following tests show what is really written to the page when a DDL query is run and where the default non null value goes.

I first create a test table and add 1 row:

```
create table Test(id int identity(2, 1) not null
    , v0 char(10) not null
    , v1 int
    , v2 varchar(10)
    , v3 datetime
)
go
insert into Test(v0, v1, v2, v3)
select 'ABC', null, 'xxxx', '2015-09-18 10:29:20.683'
go
```

If we look at the data from the page for this row with `DBCC Page`, we get:

```
dbcc ind('Test', 'Test', 1)
DBCC TRACEON (3604);
dbcc page('Test', 1, 119, 3) 

0000000000000000:   3000'1e00 '02000000 '41424320 20202020 2020'cbf3  
                         ^^^^ null bitmap location
                               ^ id = 2
                                         ^ v0 = ABC + 17 chars
                                                                ^ v1 is null...
0000000000000014:   0200'cdda ac0017a5 0000'0500 04'0100'29 00'787878
                  ...v1   
                         ^ v3 = 2015-09-18 10:29:20.683'
                                            ^ 5 columns
                                                 ^ 1 byte null bitmap location = 1e
                                                    ^ 1 var length column
                                                         ^ end of var col 1 = offset 29 (=> v2)
                                                                ^ v2 = xxxx
0000000000000028:   78
                      ^ end of v2 at offset 29
```

Now lets add a new column v4 and look at the page again for these 6 columns:

```
alter table Test2Add add v4 datetime null

0000000000000000:   3000'1e00 '02000000 '41424320 20202020 2020'cbf3
0000000000000014:   0200'cdda ac0017a5 0000'0500 04'010029 00'787878
                                            ^ still 5 columns in the null bitmap
0000000000000028:   78
```

We can see that nothing has been change and only 5 columns are present in the null bitmap

Now if we update  column v1 with value 123, we get:

```
update t set v1 = 123 from Test t

0000000000000000:   3000'2600 '02000000 '41424320 20202020 2020'7b00  
0000000000000014:   0000'cdda ac0017a5 0000'0000 b0ab24ee 0200'0600  
                                            ^ v4 value (is null)
                                                               ^^^^ 6 columns
0000000000000028:   20'010031 00'787878 78
```

We can now see that v4 has been added right after the last fixed length column (v3) and right before the column count and the null bitmap
The location of the variable length column now start at 26 (1e before the update)

We then add a new nullable column with a default contrainst:

```
alter table Test2Add add v5 datetime default('2015-09-18 10:29:20.683') null

0000000000000000:   3000'2600 '02000000 '41424320 20202020 2020'7b00      
0000000000000014:   0000'cdda ac0017a5 0000'0000 b0ab24ee 0200'0600
0000000000000028:   20'010031 00'787878 78
```

Again nothing is changed and the column does not exist on the page although a select gives the correct output:

```
id  v0          v1  v2   v3                      v4   v5
2   ABC         123 xxxx 2015-09-18 10:29:20.683 NULL NULL
```

Finally a new non nullable column v6 is added with a default constraint:

```
alter table Test2Add add v6 datetime default(getdate()) not null

0000000000000000:   3000'2600 '02000000 '41424320 20202020 2020'7b00
0000000000000014:   0000'cdda ac0017a5 0000'0000 b0ab24ee 0200'0600
0000000000000028:   20'010031 00'787878 78
```

... and there is still no change to the page. However a Select show v6 with it default value:

```
id  v0          v1  v2   v3                      v4   v5   v6
2   ABC         123 xxxx 2015-09-18 10:29:20.683 NULL NULL **2015-09-18 16:28:44.680**
```

If we insert a new row, everything is recorded this time:

```
0000000000000000:   3000'3600 '03000000 '41424320 20202020 2020'f8f5
0000000000000014:   fe07'cdda ac0017a5 0000'0000 c0b7c30e 0000'cdda
0000000000000028:   ac0017a5 0000'7570 1a0117a5 0000'0800 24'0100'41
                                  ^v6
                                                     ^ 8 columns
000000000000003C:   00'787878 78
```

So, where is the default value for v6 stored ?

Lets look at `sys.system_internals_partition_columns`:

```
select p.index_id, p.partition_number
    , pc.leaf_null_bit
    , coalesce(cx.name, c.name) as column_name
    , pc.partition_column_id
    , pc.max_inrow_length
    , pc.max_length
    , pc.key_ordinal
    , pc.leaf_offset
    , pc.is_nullable
    , pc.default_value
from sys.system_internals_partitions p
join sys.system_internals_partition_columns pc on p.partition_id = pc.partition_id
left join sys.index_columns ic on p.object_id = ic.object_id and ic.index_id = p.index_id and ic.index_column_id = pc.partition_column_id 
left join sys.columns c on p.object_id = c.object_id and ic.column_id = c.column_id 
left join sys.columns cx on p.object_id = cx.object_id and p.index_id in (0, 1) and pc.partition_column_id = cx.column_id
where p.object_id = object_id('test')
order by index_id, partition_number;
```

We can see that the `default_value` for v6 is stored there and its value is indeed `2015-09-18 16:28:44.680`
This explain why the page has not been changed for existing columns despite the default contraints and `not null`.

Now, if the table is rebuilded:

```
alter table Test2add rebuild
dbcc ind('Test', 'Test', 1) => new page id is127
dbcc page('Test2', 1, 127, 3)
```

We can see that a new page has been added and data is now stored on page 127 for row id=2:

```
0000000000000000:   3000'3600 '02000000 '41424320 20202020 2020'7b00
0000000000000014:   0000'cdda ac0017a5 0000'0000 00000000 ffff'ffff
0000000000000028:   feedecf5 fe07'1c91 0f0117a5 0000'0800 '60'0100'41
                                  ^ v6 value
                                                     ^8 columns
000000000000003C:   00'787878 78
```